# Update Approval Status field as null for new cloned quote

Tags: visual-workflow, cpq, quote, clone

I created a flow that updates the Approval Status as blank and Status as 'Draft' for newly created Cloned Quotes. I put the starting condition of the flow as below :-

This seems to work fine for some of the quotes but not all. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Is `SBQQ__Source__c` populated on the clone source object?

Comment: SBQQ__Source__c fiedl is blank on the Source record, is that the reason of this issue? As I am applying the entry condiotion in flow for the new cloned quote record that is being created.

Comment: your entry criteria says that `SBQQ__Source__c` has to be non-null

Comment: yes, that is the entry criteria of flow to trigger for the new cloned quote record being created. So, I have a source record which I am cloning and the SBQQ__Source__c for this source record is null. But the new cloned quote record that is being created by cloning the source record has the SBQQ__Source__c = Id of the source record.

Comment: this is a fast field update flow so it matters _when_ the `SBQQ__Source__c` field is given the source record's Id as it may not be available when this flow executes. Please use [edit] to elaborate

Comment: I tried Action and Related records flow as well but no help. I tried a scheduled path with 1 minute delay, it worked. This means that the Source field is getting updated in the newly created quote after the execution of my flow.

Comment: There you go!  Please add an answer below (not a comment) as a service to the Community -- you'll be able to accept your own answer (a good idea) after 48 hrs